# Is there a better way to write a swing than I'm doing right now?

Tags: sheet-music, swing

I'm currently trying to write out a song I made in another program. I used a swing like at the bottom of the picture, but I can't seem to find a way to write it down consisely. This is the best way I can think of, but is there a better way?
[image: No description]

Comment: normally on notator programs you can set the notation and give in the humanizer, random or setting the .swing in %. Are you asking for playback or for reading  a sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it out normally, and at the top say 'swing' and/or crotchet=2 tied triplet quavers and a single quaver. But in dots!  [image]

Comment: Most swing music is notated like Tim explains. An other way is to write in 12/8 or 6/8 time.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - 12/8 works far better than 6/8.

Comment: Just to make sure I completely understand, do you mean like this? https://i.imgur.com/6lbwrbL.png

Comment: That's the way to do it!

Comment: More commonly seen like this: https://images.app.goo.gl/utXVarjgLJNgxAw46

Comment: 12/8 is OK for slower tempos where swing more nearly fits a triplet timebase, i.e. the first note of each pair is close to twice the duration of the second. But at faster tempos the durations become (much) closer. At very fast tempos the durations are almost the same and the swing feel relies on the articulation. To me that's a powerful argument for this answer. Another argument is that is much easier to read.

Comment: I suppose we have to accept that the '8ths=triplets' indication is in the language, though I deplore it.  Swing isn't triplets.  It certainly isn't 12/8 - keep that for when you want a shuffle.   If you don't know the difference, listen to 'Satin Doll' then 'Blueberry Hill'.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - whilst I appreciate that swing isn't *always* triplets - a lot is, in my opinion - there just isn't another straightforward way to write it out. We're stuck with that way, and generally it's understood by players. I asked a question a long time ago about swing/shuffle, and still struggle with the concepts. That doesn't mean I can't play them - have done for 50 odd yrs.

Comment: The straightforward way to write out swing is straight 8s plus the word 'Swing'.  It's not the first time in musical history that the required performance wasn't strictly mathematically represented by the notation.